# GUI similar to messages view for Blackberry application

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, custom-controls, listfield

I want to display messages from my application exactly in the same way as that of native messaging application of Blackberry.

How do I achieve it in listfield? Also I want to add date headers that will display messages in the order in which they are received.

Please help.
Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want header grouping by date or sender etc think it's better to use VerticalFieldManager with:

LabelField (header A)
ListField  (list A)
LabelField (header B)
ListField  (list B)
...
LabelField (header Z)
ListField  (list Z)

and dynamically generate those fields on grouping.
also, implement items (and listField rows) sorting in listField constructor.

For example of complex ListField extention see [How to customize list field in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-list-field-in-blackberry)