# Blackberry - View similar to Blackberry Messenger, MSN or Gtalk

Tags: user-interface, listview, blackberry, expand, expandablelistview

A View with expand and contract list where you show, for instance, Chats, Contacts, Groups. You click on of them and expands to a list of Chats and each element of the list is a Rectangular box with User defined image, name, status (offline, online, busy) as an image and status message.

How can i program a view as described?

thanks in advance

Comment: please describe "expand" feature with more details.

Answer (score 0):

For such view you can use [ListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html).
See [SO - How to customize list field in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-list-field-in-blackberry)