# ListField font update takes effect only when user scrolls

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am developing an application which shows some user details on a screen.
I use a custom ListField as suggested by the StackOverflow question "[How to customize list field in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-list-field-in-blackberry)"

I am trying to appaly a font to each list field element, and it works well.
But when I try to give 2 different fonts for two listfields, the font is only changed when I scroll on the screen. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve it?

```
field = getField(1);
layoutChild(field, 200, fontHeight + 1);
setPositionChild(field, preferredWidth-preferredWidth/3, 3);
setFont(fontForAllElements); 
Font fontForAllElements = Font.getDefault();
fontForAllElements = fontForAllElements.derive(Font.PLAIN, 16);
```

Comment: ..................................

Comment: Uh, for one, you have to call `setFont(fontForAllElements)` **after** you actually assign `fontForAllElements` a value.

Answer (score 0):

If scrolling fixes your problem, perhaps calling [ListField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html).invalidate() will do the redrawing you need.