# Create ListField with image in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, listfield

How to create ListField with image in BlackBerry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried searching for this first? There're really lots of info on this.

For instance, check this - [How to customize a list field in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-a-list-field-in-blackberry)