# Listfield with Group header

Tags: blackberry

I need to show following content in listfield like the attached scrheenshot...

----MOVIE NAME 1-----

Theatre Name-1  Show Timing : 12:30 PM

Theatre Name-2  Show Timing : 13:20 PM

Theatre Name-3  Show Timing : 14:30 PM

----MOVIE NAME 2-----

Theatre Name-1  Show Timing : 12:30 PM

Theatre Name-2  Show Timing : 13:20 PM

Theatre Name-3  Show Timing : 14:30 PM

----MOVIE NAME 3-----

Theatre Name-1  Show Timing : 12:30 PM

Theatre Name-2  Show Timing : 13:20 PM

Theatre Name-3  Show Timing : 14:30 PM

In the above list MOVIE NAME is group header, similar to this FB list..

Please help me out ...thanks in advance..

http://www.venquet.com/fb.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add several ListField instances to one screen.

Use LabelField and ListField instances to represnent each group. LabelField instance will contain movie title, and ListField instance will represent the list of movie theaters.

Comment: in the memory and smooth scrolling point of view is it right approach?

Comment: I don't think there are another options. If your groups are of fixed size (number of items) then you can also consider stiling some rows as headers.

Answer (score 1):

Hey as Rafael said you can have multiple list field appended to your screen with header for each list.

You can customize your list field here. [custom-listfield-in-blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/custom-listfield-in-blackberry.html)

Comment: thanks neel for your effort, I made the custom listfield with manager by refering this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-a-list-field-in-blackberry