# How can I achieve this kind of List in BlackBerry?

Tags: layout, blackberry, java-me, software-design

I am making my first application for BlackBerry (OS 6.0+) and I have to define a screen like in the image below. I have read about `RichList` but its not allowed to be added below the other components.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

What I want is the part (list) below the wide `ButtonField`. The white boxes should contain images and the scribbles in front of it should contain text. This "list items" are populated dynamically.

As you can see, this very-much resembles the layout of a `RichList`, but I can't seem to add it to the `VerticalFieldManager` that I have used as the main container of components.

So if anyone can help me get this screen, I'm really grateful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using `ListField`? You can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1881319/431639

Comment: @Rupak I checked it out.. But is there any efficient way of doing that? ('cos this application may have large number of rows). If I get no satisfactory answer, then I'll resolve to doing that.

Comment: Not sure about the efficiency in case of large lists, but it is much more efficient and effective than using customized `VerticalFieldManager` which will contain the row items. Also it is possible to populate the list with new items and delete items from the list dynamically using the current selected row information. So I think this can be used with some dynamic data erasing/adding.

Comment: @Rupak OK, thanks for the link and tips.. Ravi's answer is also good, so I'll check both of them out. But I'll select Ravi's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement ListFieldCallback and overwrite all methods. There you will see "drawListRow" method. You need to draw Images on left and text on write on this method index wise. like this:-

```
    ListData ld = (ListData) rows.elementAt(index);

             g.drawText(ld.name,  30+extraSpaceDelete, y
            + (listItemHeight - g.getFont().getHeight()) / 2);

    g.drawText(ld.address,  30+extraSpaceDelete, (y
            + (listItemHeight - g.getFont().getHeight()) / 2)+(g.getFont().getAscent()+10));

    g.drawBitmap(0, y + listItemH - 3, Display.getWidth(), 3,
            separator_line, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Now I have an idea how to do this.. :)