# Custom List Field with Custom ObjectChoiceField in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, custom-lists

I am a new BB developer working on android simultaneously, I am preparing a project containing list and object choice fields in both the languages.

In blackberry, I have a list of 10 elements and on each element row I need to show an arrow button on click of that button a ObjectChoiceField will pops up.

Here, it is clear that the list and obejctchoice field both are custom.

I am very confused please let me know, how this can be achieved.

Thanx in advance..!:|[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share a screenshot/sketch? Is the ObjectChoiceField needed to be placed on the row of the ListField, or it can be displayed on another popup screen?

Comment: list will be custom - agreed but why you want custom choice field ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// customize ListField
[How to customize a ListField in BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-a-list-field-in-blackberry)

To get clicked item just add below function to code

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        Field field = this.getLeafFieldWithFocus();

        if(field instanceof ListField){
            System.out.println("navigationClick Yes Yes you clicked list item ");
            ListField listField = (ListField)field;
            // this will give you clicked index.
                    int index = listField.getSelectedIndex();
            // pop up your Object choice field here...
        }
        return true;
}
```