# how to show details when click on list filed?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Hi Friend's i want to show details when i click on this list field with image(location)means u take any lat long and show with it a image map.so please help me to solve this problem.

How is it possible please help me.
Thanks

[on this link show the list field i am also create like this listfiled and when i click  and show details with image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-a-list-field-in-blackberry)

How is it possible please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here I am giving some example try this (assign index to each field in the list view). You can display your details in NewsScreen().

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    int index;
    System.out.println("CLICKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    index = this.getFieldWithFocusIndex();

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewsScreen());      
        }
    });

    System.out.println("OUTPUTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT"+this.getFieldWithFocusIndex());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: getFieldWithFocusIndex();what i write here

Comment: I had given the navigation click code for your list field.let us consider your list field contains 10 fields, assign indexes to these fields like 1,2,3,..10(you can give also in dynamical ).if you click on 3rd field then it displays according details of that index 3.

Comment: getFieldWithFocusIndex();   is default getter method for focused field

Comment: thanks buddy it's working but how i show image map on next page.

Comment: and ask your requirement in another question

Comment: my reputation is low so i cant mark ur answer.my another question how i set header and footer in blackberry.

Comment: @user1456442 Your reputation doesn't allow you to **Upvote** an answer, however it sure allows you to **Accept** an answer. To accept an answer, you must click on the *check mark* besides the answer. Check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the image map String URI or bitmap byte to the other screen and show it 
`UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewsScreen(IMAGE MAP STRING));

        }
    });`

Comment: that was the answer for your qustion "how i show image map on next page"