# How can i create custom listField?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to customize a ListField in BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872160/how-to-customize-a-listfield-in-blackberry)

Hi Friend's i want to create custom list field.
and also want to add image over it.

[image: like this image.So please help me how can i do this with navigation click event]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1881319/1122385 this Answers it is very useful to you.

Comment: you should have searched before you posted such a general issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can create custom list field by implementing ListFieldCallback and also by overriding the drawListrow Method.  Then You can create your custom code inside of that method.