# wrap text of custom listfield

Tags: blackberry

i need to make list of news so i have implement custom listfield with one thumb and two text and it draw with `graphics` object.it all gone fine and give me result as expect but there are something problem with **text wraping** i am basically android developer and there are `wrap content` file allow that set textfiled automatically but in this case there are bind one text over second. i have refer customer listfield [from here](http://mobibug.blogspot.in/2011/08/custom-listfield-in-blackberry.html)

Here is screen::

[image]

**Code::**

```
public class CustomListField extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback {

    private Vector _listData;

    private int _MAX_ROW_HEIGHT = 80;

    public CustomListField(Vector data) {

        _listData = data;

        setSize(_listData.size());

        setSearchable(true);

        setCallback(this);

        setRowHeight(_MAX_ROW_HEIGHT);

    }

    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {

        XYRect rect = new XYRect();

        graphics.setGlobalAlpha(150);

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        getFocusRect(rect);

        drawHighlightRegion(graphics, HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS, true, rect.x, rect.y,
                rect.width, rect.height);

    }

    public int moveFocus(int amount, int status, int time) {

        this.invalidate(this.getSelectedIndex());

        return super.moveFocus(amount, status, time);

    }

    public void onFocus(int direction) {

        super.onFocus(direction);

    }

    protected void onUnFocus() {

        this.invalidate(this.getSelectedIndex());

    }

    public void refresh() {

        this.getManager().invalidate();

    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
            int y, int w) {

        ListRander listRander = (ListRander) _listData.elementAt(index);

        graphics.setGlobalAlpha(255);

        graphics.setFont(Font.getDefault().getFontFamily().getFont(Font.PLAIN,
                24));

        final int margin = 5;

        final Bitmap thumb = listRander.getListThumb();

        final String listHeading = listRander.getListTitle();

        final String listDesc = listRander.getListDesc();

        final String listDesc2 = listRander.getListDesc2();

        final Bitmap nevBar = listRander.getNavBar();

        // list border

        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        graphics.drawRect(0, y, w, _MAX_ROW_HEIGHT);

        // thumbnail border & thumbnail image

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        graphics.drawRoundRect(margin - 2, y + margin - 2,
                thumb.getWidth() + 2, thumb.getHeight() + 2, 5, 5);

        graphics.drawBitmap(margin, y + margin, thumb.getWidth(), thumb
                .getHeight(), thumb, 0, 0);

        // drawing texts

        //graphics.setFont(FontGroup.fontBold);

        graphics.drawText(listHeading, 2 * margin + thumb.getWidth(), y
                + margin);

        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        //graphics.setFont(FontGroup.smallFont);

        graphics.drawText(listDesc, 2 * margin + thumb.getWidth(), y + margin
                + 20);

        graphics.drawText(listDesc2, 2 * margin + thumb.getWidth(), y + margin
                + 32);

        // draw navigation button

        final int navBarPosY = y
                + (_MAX_ROW_HEIGHT / 2 - nevBar.getHeight() / 2);

        final int navBarPosX = Graphics.getScreenWidth() - nevBar.getWidth()
                + margin;

        graphics.drawBitmap(navBarPosX, navBarPosY, nevBar.getWidth(), nevBar
                .getHeight(), nevBar, 0, 0);

    }

    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {

        String rowString = (String) _listData.elementAt(index);

        return rowString;

    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {

        for (Enumeration e = _listData.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {

            String rowString = (String) e.nextElement();

            if (rowString.startsWith(prefix)) {

                return _listData.indexOf(rowString);

            }

        }

        return 0;

    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {

        return 3 * listField.getRowHeight();
    }
}

/*
 * protected boolean trackwheelClick (int status, int time) {
 * 
 * invalidate(getSelectedIndex());
 * 
 * Dialog.alert(" U have selected :" + getSelectedIndex());
 * 
 * return super.trackwheelClick(status, time);
 * 
 * }
```

**Update:**

new screen :: [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: I am going to post code here, please remove comment

Comment: decrease the font size using        FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
Font font = fontFamily[1].getFont(FontFamily.CBTF_FONT, 15);

Comment: Use this link, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1881319/431639. Study the code carefully, it is a nice one. Check how each row draws itself using delegate manager.

Comment: @Rupak yes there are 80% problem are solved but now it display text in Lablfield like "List Name ....." so what i do for display full text.

Comment: If you are using the solution provided in the above link, then you only need to change the construction of all the `LabelField`s only. Just don't use `DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS` style to construct a `LabelField` if you want to display full text.

Comment: @Rupak now it display entire text but its out of list item boundary you can see my update question ...

Comment: @Rupak so the question is how can i increase automatically its listrow height as per text size

Comment: It is not possible to set different height for each rows in `ListField`. So you have to determine the height of the FieldManager you are using as a row. But if you really need different height for different rows, then you need to use `VerticalFieldManager` (extremely slower approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it programmatic , We don't have label field in a list because we are rendering it using graphics. 
So i used to do a workaround to do so , i calculate the no of pixels availabale for my custom font for text , then how much space it will take i will give with three period signs. 
You can use this code if , it can help you, use it under drawListRow method

```
String name =(String)ht.get("title");
xTotal= f2.getAdvance(name);
xAvail= Display.getWidth() - <bitmap>.getWidth() - 30;
if(xTotal > xAvail)
{
forLabel= name.length() * xAvail / xTotal ;
    name = name.substring(0, forLabel - 3) + "...";

}
```

use name string variable in place of graphics.drawText.