# Can I paint RichList each row with a Background Image? (Blackberry)

Tags: listview, blackberry

I want an arrow image placing right side of the row of RichList. But since RichList only allows an image to be on the LEFT side of its list. So I thought why don't paint a row of a Richlist like with arrow on right side.

So can we paint each row with any bitmap image while using RichList?

Comment: You are starting to want to do a lot of customization with the RichList class.  I'm not sure it's well-suited for that.  You may find that you need to [use the ListField as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1881319/119114).  Make note of Arhimed's comment about performance.  The BlackBerry samples have more examples, but I'm not sure RichList is going to be right for you, if you want to keep modifying the way it looks.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I used ImageListField instead of it. I'm very disappointed with the RichList, so many limitations.